# Panel is empty after changing cards in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm codding selection sort visualization. So, I got an issue: when I change panels(when I'm in main menu and I press button for visualization) I want my array to be painted on visualization panel, but it doesn't happen. I get empty panel, nothing's there.
I also use SwingExplorer Integration v2 plugin for itellij and it tells me, that menu panel is not visible and visualization panel is visible, so the way of changing panels is correct. I also tried both methods paint() and paintComponent(), it didn't help.

Sorting class is the panel where array visualization will happen.
ArrayVis class is the array visualization(not ready yet ofc).

What am I doing wrong? Why is my visualization panel empty?

I'm new in java, so I hope you help me!

Code:

**Main.java**

```
import project.MainMenu;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainMenu();
    }
}
```

**MainMenu.java**

```
package project;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel visualization;
    private JPanel menu;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton visualizeButton;
    private JLabel description;
    Dimension screen;

    public MainMenu() {
        menu = new JPanel();
        visualization = new Sorting();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 1);
        layout.setVgap(10);

        menu.setLayout(layout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));


        label = new JLabel("Сортировка выбором");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(36.0f));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(getX());

        description = new JLabel("<html><span>Описание какое-то сортировки</span></html>");
        description.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(20.0f));

        visualizeButton = new JButton("Посмотреть визуализацию");
        visualizeButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            boolean clicked = false;

            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                visualizeButton.setBackground(new Color(155, 239, 245));
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                if (!clicked)
                    visualizeButton.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
            }
/// changing panels
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                clicked = true;
                mainPanel.add(visualization, "visualization");
                cardLayout.show(mainPanel,"visualization");
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setSize(50,40);
        buttonPanel.add(visualizeButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        menu.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        menu.add(description, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        menu.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        mainPanel.add(menu,"menu");

        cardLayout.show(mainPanel,"menu");

        add(mainPanel);

        screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Сортировка выбором");
        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Sorting.java**

```
package project;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Sorting extends JPanel {
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton addNum;
    private JButton startVisualizing;
    private JButton resetArray;
    private int x = 15;
    private int[] arr;
    private int y = 15;

    public Sorting(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        arr = new int[]{1,2,3};
        add(new ArrayVis(arr,x,y));
        x += 10 * arr.length;

    }

    public void selectionSort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            int helper = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = helper;
        }
    }
}
```

**ArrayVis.java**

```
package project;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ArrayVis extends JComponent {
    private int[] arr;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public ArrayVis(int[] arr,int x, int y){
        this.arr = arr;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            g.drawString(Integer.toString(arr[i]),x,y);
            x += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted was a confusing mess.  Java has methods so you can break your code into understandable bite-size pieces.

Here's the GUI I created.  I reduced the size of the GUI so it fits better in the answer.

[image: menu]

Here's the drawing component.

[image: visualization]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` and the `JPanels` into separate methods and classes.  This allows me to separate my concerns and makes the code much much easier for people to read and understand.

You use the `paintComponent` method of a `JComponent` to do your drawing.  The first line of the `paintComponent` method must always be `super.paintComponent(g);`.

I didn't include your `Sorting` class.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but sorting an array is done separately from creating the view.  The only thing the view does is display your application model.  Period.  Nothing else.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class VisualizationExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new VisualizationExample());
    }

    private final CardLayout cardLayout;

    private final JPanel mainPanel;

    public VisualizationExample() {
        this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        this.mainPanel = createMainPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Сортировка выбором");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        panel.add(createMenuPanel(), "menu");
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
        panel.add(new ArrayVisualization(arr, 10, 30), "visualization");

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createMenuPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 10));
        mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Сортировка выбором");
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(36.0f));
        mainPanel.add(label);

        JLabel description = new JLabel(
                "<html><span>Описание какое-то сортировки</span></html>");
        description.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(20.0f));
        mainPanel.add(description);

        JButton visualizeButton = new JButton("Посмотреть визуализацию");
        visualizeButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
        mainPanel.add(visualizeButton);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    public void showArrayVisualization() {
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "visualization");
    }

    public class ArrayVisualization extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int[] arr;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public ArrayVisualization(int[] arr, int x, int y) {
            this.arr = arr;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(arr[i]), x, y);
                x += 24;
            }
        }

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private final VisualizationExample view;

        public ButtonListener(VisualizationExample view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            view.showArrayVisualization();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @kirin: You might want to read this [Sort Animation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/bubble-sort-animation#readme) description so you can see what goes into creating this type of GUI.